# How to listen to OnFieldChanged if EditContext is CascadingParameter

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I need to subscribe to OnFieldCHanged but can't create EditContext manually because I am using Blazored FluentValidation and it does not work properly if EditContext is set instead of a Model.

However if I try to subscribe to OnFieldChanged, CascadingParameter EditContext is null.

Is there a way to do it?

I am using .net 7.

Profile.razor

```
<EditForm Model="@Member" OnValidSubmit="@SaveMember" Context="CurrentEditContext" id="MemberForm">
    <FluentValidationValidator @ref="Validator" Options="@(options => options.IncludeRuleSets(ValidationRuleSets.ToArray()))" />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <InputDate @bind-Value="@Member.DateOfBirth" />
</EditForm>
```

Profile.razor.cs

```cs
public partial class Profile
{
    [Parameter]
    public FluentValidationValidator Validator { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    public HashSet<string> ValidationRuleSets { get; set; } = new() { MemberDtoValidator.NewMember };

    public MemberDto Member { get; set; } = new();

    [CascadingParameter]
    public EditContext CurrentEditContext { get; set; }   

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        if (CurrentEditContext is not null)
            CurrentEditContext.OnFieldChanged += Context_OnFieldChanged;
    }   
     
    private void Context_OnFieldChanged(object? sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It works");
    }

    // rest of code omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: Show the code you have - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer